# How to fully parallelize a Java8 stream through buffering?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have some code like this:

```
Stream<Item> stream = listPaths.parallelStream().flatMap(path -> { ... })
```

I have also added this:

```
    System.setProperty(
            "java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism",
            String.valueOf(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() * 4));
```

Later I call `stream.forEach(...)`

However, I have found that on a machine with 32 cores, only 5 to 8 cores are utilized.

I believe what is happening is that the code inside flatMap() and the code inside the forEach() suffer of I/O Latency issues for different external resources, and returns data in "fits and starts" -- a bad combination with the "pull" nature of streams.

Is there a simple (idiomatic, not "go write your own 200 lines of code") to wrap the stream into some sort of "stream buffer" that would keep the source stream fully utilized (pulling at max threads) while feeding the forEach()?

Comment: Why not use reactive streams? Sounds like a perfect match for your problem.

Comment: What is the actual implementation type of listPaths?

Comment: @LouisWasserman it's an `ArrayList`

Comment: @Prashant you should turn your comment into an answer. Finally a reason to look into Java9

Comment: Hahaha! Java 8 is already deprecated - Long time ago. `Flowable` does sound good! Comments are for showing directions. As a matter of fact, I know about rxJava and kotlin thank java 9!

Comment: Why use streams in the first place of you need better scheduling control? Just iterate into an `ExecutorService#submit`.

Comment: "a machine with 32 cores, only 5 to 8 cores are utilized" -> I think it's about thread pool size, not cup core size.  you can print out the thread number/name in flatmap to find out how many thread are started/executed. 32 threads started doesn't mean 32 cores are utilized. one core may be able to handle multiple threads if it's IO bounded task.

Answer (score 0):

The best way in my opinion is to use reactive streams. There are many ways to go about this:

- Using `<Flowable>`
- Using `RxJava`

Or thirdly, using `Spring's Reactor framework`
They all have scheduling mechanism. Personally, I can use one of these algorithms and still be happy with them unless I want to write 200 lines of code.